# How to call powershell script from groovy

Tags: powershell, jenkins-groovy

I have a working jenkins pipeline script and added a call invoking powershell script. This works, if I hard-code the path. But if I use the variable, (modeled based on the bat call), it errors. What would be the correct way to invoke the powershell script?

```
stage('Build') {
        when {
            anyOf {branch 'develop'}
        }
        steps {
            powershell "\"${WORKSPACE}\"/AssemblyUpdater.ps1"
            bat "AFDownload.bat"
            bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\" \"${WORKSPACE}\"/Solution/BuildCSharp.sln /t:clean"
            bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\" \"${WORKSPACE}\"/Solution/BuildCSharp.sln /t:build /p:Configuration=Debug"
        }
    }
```

This is the current working hard-coded version:

```
powershell "c:/jenkins/workspace/develop_2/AssemblyUpdater.ps1"
```

Comment: *what* does it error?

Comment: Parse error - You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.

Comment: Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: You should add the full error formatted as code. The error would tell you which '/' it's complaining about.

Comment: It will take a while now, since I have to break our product build to get the exact error. I tried all combinations and modeled the call based on bat, but was not successful. Maybe powershell calls dont work that way, I just want someone who knows groovy to chime either way. Am I doing it right or not?

Comment: Yeah hopefully someone stumbles across this that knows groovy. The complete error should've been your first resource to resolve the issue. Errors are a feature of the languages and shouldn't be ignored. To me, it looks like your path separators are backwards, maybe try `\ instead of /``

Comment: Agree on value or error message. Years of programing taught me the value of it. If you look at the `bat` call you can see the path which use similar. This is how it is now, hardcoded `powershell "c:/jenkins/workspace/develop_2/AssemblyUpdater.ps1"`

Comment: So you're not going to try switching them? You showed one hard coded line but there are two within the bat that you can try switching. Worth a shot. Good luck to ya.

Comment: So switching is the one that causes it to error out.